# Switch case return

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, return, case

I'm new to javascript. I'm trying to write a simple switch case return program. But for some reason its not working. I don't get any error message. Output is simply blank

```
var day;
switch (new Date().getDay()) {
  case 0: return "0";
  case 1:return "1";
  case 2:return "2";
  case 3:return "3";
  case 4:return "4";
  case 5:return "5";
  case 6:return "6";
}
```

Comment: are you logging it in somewhere?

Comment: Where is it returning to? Instead of return, try making it day = 1,2 etc

Comment: That's an ilegal return statement, or are you puting it in a function?

Comment: Also if you just want to return the same number as string you just need to put (new Date().getDay()).toString() instead

Comment: function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
  const matches = [
    "abc.org",
    "*.xyz.org",
    "test.com",
  ];


  for (const match of matches) {
    if (shExpMatch(host, match)) {
      return "PROXY 109.156.228.50:1337";
    }
  }


  return "DIRECT";
}

Comment: We have this PAC file that we need to update the IP address manually everyday. And we wanna automate that.

Answer (score 1):

Use this because return return the answer to function not the switch

```
var day=xyz()
function xyz(){
switch (new Date().getDay()) {
 case 0: return "0";
 case 1:return "1";
 case 2:return "2";
 case 3:return "3";
 case 4:return "4";
 case 5:return "5";
 case 6:return "6";
}
}
console.log(day)
```

Or you can do in this manner if any doubts comment

```
var day;
switch (new Date().getDay()) {
  case 0:
    day = "0";
    break;
  case 1:
    day = "1";
    break;
  case 2:
     day = "2";
    break;
  case 3:
    day = "3";
    break;
  case 4:
    day = "4";
    break;
  case 5:
    day = "5";
    break;
  case 6:
    day = "6";
}
console.log(day)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I know this works. But I'm actually trying to auto rotate the proxy  IP address everyday with the above script. I was just testing it with the number value first to see if it works

Comment: @Najmin Farmana welcome and thats sound cool can you tell me what are you doing because i dont know about proxy I really wanna know how you are changing proxy

Comment: function FindProxyForURL(url, host) { const matches = [ "abc.org", "*.xyz.org", "test.com", ]; for (const match of matches) { if (shExpMatch(host, match)) { return "PROXY 109.156.228.50:1337"; } } return "DIRECT"; }        we currently rotate the proxy address manually. We wanna automate the rotaion based on the dates

Comment: So is you problem solved if yes close this question and upvote my answer @Najmin Farmana

Comment: @Najmin Farmana So can I help just tell me what you want to do on what basis like date or day and change with what

Comment: I just wanna switch the IP address everyday i.e Monday: address 1, Tuesday: Address2 etc

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of Switch Statement should look like

```
switch(expression) {
  case x:
    // code block
    break;
  case y:
    // code block
    break;
  default:
    // code block
}
```

Check this solution:

```js
var day;
switch (new Date().getDay()) {
  case 0:
    day = 0;
    break;
  case 1:
    day = 1;
    break;
  case 2:
     day = 2;
    break;
  case 3:
    day = 3;
    break;
  case 4:
    day = 4;
    break;
  case 5:
    day = 5;
    break;
  case 6:
    day = 6;
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Your day is: " + day;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```